# identification of Forest cover area by using eCognition Software

Tags: ndvi, ecognition

How to find forest cover area by using eCognition software?

I'm trying to find vegetation by using NDVI in the ruleset but it takes vegetation too with the forest.

Can I use any other filter along with the NDVI to identify only the forest cover area?

Answer (score 1):

Your question depends on which kind of image are you using, which sensor and its bandwidths.
Using NDVI you can try finding a threshold. If it is not enough to separate your classes you will need a more complex approach, like using multiple thresholdings or try a classification algorithm.